# What is the actual reason behind intestinal gas?

Tags: nutrition, digestion, mental-health, gastroenterology, weight

I have some symptoms of **IBS**. And the most irritating problem I'm dealing with is **intestinal gas**. I'm taking medicines but they don't seem working. Neither it is curing IBS nor the gas problem.

I'm taking enough fiber (salad, vegetables, fruits etc.). I don't eat any fast food or something like that. I walk early in the morning, before dinner and light walk after dinner. I do some light **exercises/Yoga**. Yet, I'm suffering from intestinal gas. Bloating is okay but this gas causes pain in my lower part and I've to go to toilet 2-3 times daily to pass the gas only (most of the times). I **can't evacuate** at single time.

So I want to find the root cause of this gas problem and want to find solution for it.

I have three queries to ask in my case:

1. Does constipation cause intestinal gas?
2. Do some food cause gas and then gas cause constipation?
3. My stools are not like they should be (sometimes liquid, sometimes hard and color varies, and all with gas).

   (a) What can be the reason of this? Bad digestion of food or the constipation   (caused by gas?)?
   (b) Is it possible that food is digested properly but gas causes the variations and bad stools?

**Two** more thing that can help you answer better is that **1st:** **I think a lot** (I don't actually know if it's normal or a lot) about these problems, search many times on internet for solutions. I think like every **half an hour** about these problems. **2nd:** I'm underweight. Everyone calls me skinny. I even think about it many times a day and feel little ashamed and bad. My weight is **57** Kg and I'm **aged 24**.

Is this thinking is causing all problems and even IBS?

**NOTE:** I take sufficient sleep. **7-8** hours per day. There are no sleeping disorders.

I hope you understand my problem and you can answer it. I shall be thankful to you.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing they occurred because of 1) personal health questions, and 2) multiple questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual mechanism of intestinal gas is that "normal intestinal bacteria" in the large intestine produce it. If you consume certain nutrients, these bacteria will consume them and produce gas. Everyone has these bacteria, so this is not a problem, the problem can be nutrients by which you "feed them":

1. **Soluble fiber** in foods, such as barley, oats, legumes (beans, peas, lentils) and some fruits. Check for more detailed [list of foods high in soluble fiber](http://www.nutrientsreview.com/carbs/dietary-fiber-soluble-insoluble.html).
2. **Lactose,** mainly in milk, but also in ice cream or yogurt (not in cheese or butter). People with lactose intolerance cannot digest lactose, so this travels from the small to large intestine, where bacteria degrade it and produce gas.
3. **Fructose** in certain fruits (apples, pears, mango, agave), honey and beverages sweetened with high fructose corn syrup (HFCS) can cause bloating and lose stools in individuals with fructose malabsorption.

To reduce all 3 nutrients at once you may consider a [low-FODMAP diet](http://www.med.monash.edu/cecs/gastro/fodmap/low-high.html).

Constipation may worsen bloating because intestinal bacteria have more time to degrade substances in your stool. Constipation can be prevented by being physically active (walking), drinking enough water (not "a lot," just enough) and avoiding certain foods. People with IBS commonly report that sugary foods, carbonated, caffeinated and alcoholic beverages, cheese and chocolate...and certain other foods...irritate them.

**EDIT:** Few more causes of irregular bowel movements and bloating:

- Intestinal parasites, including worms and unicellular parasites, like Giardia (stool tests are available)
- Celiac disease - an intolerance to gluten, which is in wheat, rye and barley.
- Chronic infection of stomach by the bacterium H. pylori can cause bloating in the upper abdomen--this is stomach bloating--a typical symptom that can differ it from intestinal bloating is frequent burping (belching).

Two common causes of constipation are dehydration and anxiety.

Excessive worrying may worsen IBS and is probably one of the causes of IBS. But thinking how to solve stomach problems is just OK.

Comment: Thank you it provided me some good knowledge about things. Could you please tell if being underweight can also cause digestion problems? Also, can gas be the reason for constipation?

Comment: Being somewhat underweight by itself should not be a reason for constipation or digestive problems of any kind. Being underweight because of poor diet resulting in nutrient deficiencies, such as iron deficiency, could contribute to constipation, though. Iron deficiency may be more common in vegans. They are blood tests for mineral and vitamin deficiencies available. I also updated my answer above.

Comment: Theoretically, excessive gas could worsen constipation, because pain from bloating could make you constipated, but this is overthinking and I don't know if it leads anywhere. The focus should be on removing gas-producing and constipating foods and concentrating on work goals.

Comment: Are apples and bananas good in IBS? At that site, banana is listed in Low FODMAP so it should be okay. Apple is in High. Should I quit apples to stop gas problems?

Comment: Apples can be a problem for some people with IBS. One practical approach to eliminating diet, such as low-FODMAP diet, is to stop eating most foods listed as "to avoid," wait a week or so to see if it helps and then starting to introduce some of them back one by one. If a newly introduced food does not cause problems within 2 days, it's probably fine. Then the next food can be tried. A low-FODMAP diet lists contain exact foods to avoid, but for a given person, only some of those foods are usually problematic and others are fine.

Comment: Did you see the answer below? How can I know if I have gas in Large intestine or in lower part of small intestine? Things are becoming very complex :(

Comment: You can't always say where gas is...but: gas in the stomach (H pylori infection) and in upper part of the small intestine (celiac disease, SIBO) is usually associated with excessive burping. Gas in both small and large intestine (colon) is associated with flatulence. But this theoretical thinking does not lead far...One needs to eliminate some foods...If stopping milk helps, its's likely lactose intolerance. If stopping eating apples and pears helps, it's likely fructose malabsorption...It's not where the gas is, it's elimination of which food helps. If no help >> doctor.

Comment: Right now I've stopped taking all milk and related products. Will tell you later.

Comment: Even after removing dairy products, apples I have gas problems. I'm not taking them since 7-8 days. In our area, the main food is Indian Chapatti made from Wheat flour. We eat them with salad and vegetable as breakfast, lunch and dinner. Is that reason for gas? Also, I eat some wet grams in the morning.

Comment: Eliminating only a single food at the time may not help in identifying the problem. If someone has fructose malabsorption, for example, he needs to remove most foods high in fructose, not only apples. So, a better approach is to go on a broad, strict elimination diet for a week - and if it helps, introducing certain foods back - one by one, every other day. The other approach is to use intuition and eliminate certain suspicious foods, even if it is no explanation why would irritate someone. Certain foods just irritate some people. You do not need to always understand the exact mechanism.

Comment: I read many articles these days and one thing in common they say is that if your food nutrients are not absorbed properly, I'll all the symptoms that I've stated. And I think it's the actual reason. Could you please suggest what should I do in this case? One more thing, my local doctor sometimes give me medicines and my digestion becomes absolutely perfect. I think it is because the medicines help absorb nutrients properly. Please reply one last time, what you think. Thank you.

Comment: It would help to know which exact medicine (the brand or generic name) helps.

Comment: I don't remember :(

Comment: If you can't remember then you do not find them that important? If someone has normal blood levels of vitamins/minerals and no diarrhea, he less likely needs drugs. One possible start is to go with a strict low-FODMAP diet for 4 days, and if it helps, introducing some foods back--one by one--every other day. Vegetarians who think they can't afford such diet can try exclude only the main foods from that list. I believe IBS is caused by stress and triggered by certain foods. Concentrating on work rather than on the details of digestion, plus adjusting the diet as necessary can help.

Comment: Thank you. I think problem is stress. I don't meet much people. I laugh 1-2 times hardly (actually smile that's too on Funny posts on social networks). Thoughts are always running into my mind, especially about career, bad health, being underweight. And when someone mocks me I feel very bad but I never reply or show anger. I just 'eat' it. When someone criticizes me, I listen and feel very bad and become little angry inside. But I don't show it. Are these things stress and cause all problems?

Comment: Stress is everything what comes from outside (people, weather, food..) or inside (thoughts, emotions, pain...) and shake you and can throw you out of peace. It is not wise to have all people as judges. Concentrating on things one believes in the heart are right to do can give him real and convincing emotional peace. When you feel that peace that tells you that you are doing right and people are still criticizing you can know they are wrong.

Comment: What does it mean? Should I stop caring in negative manner how people react to me when I'm not wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's one thing. Sometimes you need to ignore what people say not swallow everything.